# Big CSS transition not fluid

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions, transition

I have a CSS transition going on, and it lags.

It's a lot of css I'm trying to animate:

```
@keyframes text-shadow {
from {
  text-shadow: 0 0 transparent;
}
to {
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent,1px 1px #9fcdf9,2px 2px #9fcdf9,3px 3px       #9fcdf9,4px 4px #9fcdf9,5px 5px #9fcdf9,6px 6px #9fcdf9,7px 7px #9fcdf9,8px 8px #9fcdf9,9px 9px #9fcdf9,10px 10px #9fcdf9,11px 11px #9fcdf9,12px 12px #9fcdf9,13px 13px #9fcdf9,14px 14px #9fcdf9,15px 15px #9fcdf9,16px 16px #9fcdf9,17px 17px #9fcdf9,18px 18px #9fcdf9,19px 19px #9fcdf9,20px 20px #9fcdf9,21px 21px #9fcdf9,22px 22px #9fcdf9,23px 23px #9fcdf9,24px 24px #9fcdf9,25px 25px #9fcdf9,26px 26px #9fcdf9,27px 27px #9fcdf9,28px 28px #9fcdf9,29px 29px #9fcdf9,30px 30px #9fcdf9,31px 31px #9fcdf9,32px 32px #9fcdf9,33px 33px #9fcdf9,34px 34px #9fcdf9,35px 35px #9fcdf9,36px 36px #9fcdf9,37px 37px #9fcdf9,38px 38px #9fcdf9,39px 39px #9fcdf9,40px 40px #9fcdf9,41px 41px #9fcdf9,42px 42px #9fcdf9,43px 43px #9fcdf9,44px 44px #9fcdf9,45px 45px #9fcdf9,46px 46px #9fcdf9,47px 47px #9fcdf9,48px 48px #9fcdf9,49px 49px #9fcdf9,50px 50px #9fcdf9,51px 51px #9fcdf9,52px 52px #9fcdf9,53px 53px #9fcdf9,54px 54px #9fcdf9,55px 55px #9fcdf9,56px 56px #9fcdf9,57px 57px #9fcdf9,58px 58px #9fcdf9,59px 59px #9fcdf9,60px 60px #9fcdf9,61px 61px #9fcdf9,62px 62px #9fcdf9,63px 63px #9fcdf9,64px 64px #9fcdf9,65px 65px #9fcdf9,66px 66px #9fcdf9,67px 67px #9fcdf9,68px 68px #9fcdf9,69px 69px #9fcdf9,70px 70px #9fcdf9,71px 71px #9fcdf9,72px 72px #9fcdf9,73px 73px #9fcdf9,74px 74px #9fcdf9,75px 75px #9fcdf9,76px 76px #9fcdf9,77px 77px #9fcdf9,78px 78px #9fcdf9,79px 79px #9fcdf9,80px 80px #9fcdf9,81px 81px #9fcdf9,82px 82px #9fcdf9,83px 83px #9fcdf9,84px 84px #9fcdf9,85px 85px #9fcdf9,86px 86px #9fcdf9,87px 87px #9fcdf9,88px 88px #9fcdf9,89px 89px #9fcdf9,90px 90px #9fcdf9,91px 91px #9fcdf9,92px 92px #9fcdf9,93px 93px #9fcdf9,94px 94px #9fcdf9,95px 95px #9fcdf9,96px 96px #9fcdf9,97px 97px #9fcdf9,98px 98px #9fcdf9,99px 99px #9fcdf9,100px 100px #9fcdf9,101px 101px #9fcdf9,102px 102px #9fcdf9,103px 103px #9fcdf9,104px 104px #9fcdf9,105px 105px #9fcdf9,106px 106px #9fcdf9,107px 107px #9fcdf9,108px 108px #9fcdf9,109px 109px #9fcdf9,110px 110px #9fcdf9,111px 111px #9fcdf9,112px 112px #9fcdf9,113px 113px #9fcdf9,114px 114px #9fcdf9,115px 115px #9fcdf9,116px 116px #9fcdf9,117px 117px #9fcdf9,118px 118px #9fcdf9,119px 119px #9fcdf9,120px 120px #9fcdf9,121px 121px #9fcdf9,122px 122px #9fcdf9,123px 123px #9fcdf9,124px 124px #9fcdf9,125px 125px #9fcdf9,126px 126px #9fcdf9,127px 127px #9fcdf9,128px 128px #9fcdf9,129px 129px #9fcdf9,130px 130px #9fcdf9,131px 131px #9fcdf9,132px 132px #9fcdf9,133px 133px #9fcdf9,134px 134px #9fcdf9,135px 135px #9fcdf9,136px 136px #9fcdf9,137px 137px #9fcdf9,138px 138px #9fcdf9,139px 139px #9fcdf9,140px 140px #9fcdf9,141px 141px #9fcdf9,142px 142px #9fcdf9,143px 143px #9fcdf9,144px 144px #9fcdf9,145px 145px #9fcdf9,146px 146px #9fcdf9,147px 147px #9fcdf9,148px 148px #9fcdf9,149px 149px #9fcdf9,150px 150px #9fcdf9,151px 151px #9fcdf9,152px 152px #9fcdf9,153px 153px #9fcdf9,154px 154px #9fcdf9,155px 155px #9fcdf9,156px 156px #9fcdf9,157px 157px #9fcdf9,158px 158px #9fcdf9,159px 159px #9fcdf9,160px 160px #9fcdf9,161px 161px #9fcdf9,162px 162px #9fcdf9,163px 163px #9fcdf9,164px 164px #9fcdf9,165px 165px #9fcdf9,166px 166px #9fcdf9,167px 167px #9fcdf9,168px 168px #9fcdf9,169px 169px #9fcdf9,170px 170px #9fcdf9,171px 171px #9fcdf9,172px 172px #9fcdf9,173px 173px #9fcdf9,174px 174px #9fcdf9,175px 175px #9fcdf9,176px 176px #9fcdf9,177px 177px #9fcdf9,178px 178px #9fcdf9,179px 179px #9fcdf9,180px 180px #9fcdf9,181px 181px #9fcdf9,182px 182px #9fcdf9,183px 183px #9fcdf9,184px 184px #9fcdf9,185px 185px #9fcdf9,186px 186px #9fcdf9,187px 187px #9fcdf9,188px 188px #9fcdf9,189px 189px #9fcdf9,190px 190px #9fcdf9,191px 191px #9fcdf9,192px 192px #9fcdf9,193px 193px #9fcdf9,194px 194px #9fcdf9,195px 195px #9fcdf9,196px 196px #9fcdf9,197px 197px #9fcdf9,198px 198px #9fcdf9,199px 199px #9fcdf9,200px 200px #9fcdf9,201px 201px #9fcdf9,202px 202px #9fcdf9,203px 203px #9fcdf9,204px 204px #9fcdf9,205px 205px #9fcdf9,206px 206px #9fcdf9,207px 207px #9fcdf9,208px 208px #9fcdf9,209px 209px #9fcdf9,210px 210px #9fcdf9,211px 211px #9fcdf9,212px 212px #9fcdf9,213px 213px #9fcdf9,214px 214px #9fcdf9,215px 215px #9fcdf9,216px 216px #9fcdf9,217px 217px #9fcdf9,218px 218px #9fcdf9,219px 219px #9fcdf9;
   }
}
```

Is there any way to make this happen fluidly?

Comment: That isn't a **transition** it's an animation. Perhaps you would actually demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Can you provide the rest of your code so we can try it ourselves?

Comment: This is not what it actually looks like, but it's the best I can do. (Laravel was used) [codepen](http://codepen.io/g3mini/full/waoERE/)

Comment: Here's my Codepen - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/NqbLeE Perhaps you need to adjust the easing?

Comment: Setting it to `ease-in` fixes it a little bit, but It's still far from fluent

Comment: Or would there be a way to make it look like it does with 1 shadow rather than 220 shadows?

Comment: Here you have lots of easing types, maybe it can fix your problem: http://easings.net/es @g3mini

Comment: Does it lag in all browsers? I can't seem to get it to lag

Comment: It laggs on chrome & firefox

Comment: Haven't tried any others

Comment: Firefox doesn't even play the animation, it just freezes untill it's done

Comment: works perfectly smooth on my chrome

Comment: Yea, I figured that better computers/laptops actually get it to work. Unless they use firefox